# SQL Server : automatic truncate OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([KEY] VARCHAR(10), VALUE VARCHAR(5)) 

INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 'A', '10' 

INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 'ABC', '200'

----- GET DATA  
---- PROBLEMATIC VARCHAR(1) -- must be VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(1) = 'ABC'  

SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE 
WHERE [KEY] = @a
```

This code returns data for "A" .

But I need get error or warning about truncation. Is there any option to set it immediately?

I will change `DECLARE @a`, but here is OLD system and to many procedures - the option could give me more time for this changes.

Tanks for your help

David

Answer (score 0):

No, MS SQL Server doesn't have such options for variables. Server try to do silent implicit conversion.